# Angular 7 app normal anchor link not working

Tags: angular

In my angular app, for the url `http://example.com/bar-foo` I render some (static) HTML which I receive from an API

Inside that content there is this link

```
<a href="/bar-foo?show=1">Show</a>
```

So what it does is it add the query parameter to the url. However, and I don't understand why, when I click that link nothing happens

I've tried to reproduce it in a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qupl5f?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html) without success (because the link works). Any suggestions what the reason might be that this link is not working?

UPDATE: If a bit of debugging, I noticed that when I click the not-responding link it does trigger something inside `zonde.js`

[image]

which I think will call that callback which does `event.preventDefault()`. I'm not sure why zonejs does this in my case

Comment: May you try something like ```href="http://localhost:port/bar-foo?show=1"```

Comment: In your stackblitz its working fine right?

Comment: Yes, the stackblitz works fine, thats unfortunate, because it might imply that something in my app is going on which is custom

Comment: It turns out that somewhere in the code the click on a link was prevented. This was why I saw the zone.js script kick in I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You added this route in Stackblitz. Did you add this route in your project too ?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent }
];
```

And there should be an error on your browser console. Can we get that error message ?

And also you must use routing like this:

```
<a [routeLink]="['/bar-foo']" [queryParams]="{show:'1'}">Show</a>
```

Comment: It can be comment.

Comment: There is no specific route for `bar-foo`, the route that matches is `path: '**'`. Furthermore, its some static html I render so I cannot use the routing you suggest. There is no error in the browser, nothing seem to happen. If I bind a click listener to `document.body` I see the click

Comment: Then you can only define that route by adding 'html' like: `<a href="/bar-foo.html?show=1">Show</a>` But I don't think that Angular project allows you to get your static html page. You can define a component for your static HTML pages to view them. Maybe IFrame will solve your problem, or another solutions.

Comment: Not `.html`, what that link does is to change the (current) url from `/bar-foo` to `/bar-foo?show=1` to which Angular will respond

Comment: I don't think that Angular responses if there is no route for an url. @JeanlucaScaljeri You have to define a route for `/bar-foo` and you may want to use like: `bar-foo/1` and then you can get that `1` param and then you can view html pages which you want to view by getting content from your API.

Answer (score 1):

- **if You write like '?show=1' after the path so it can consider as query parameters**
- **you can try (click)="showHtml()" inside anchor tag and call API. **

and function like this

```
showHtml(){
//---API Code And result render it on html page
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the static HTML was (unintentionally) encoded/escaped/sanitized during the process of fetching it from the API and injecting it into the angular component?

Could you please provide more details / code snippets about how exactly your app fetches and injects the static HTML with the nonfunctional link?